# Change R Markdown plot width

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown

I'm starting working with R Markdown and I'm not understanding how to generate bigger plots. With today screens the plots can be much bigger.

How do I control the plots width/heigh in a Markdown report?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963962/plot-size-and-resolution-with-r-markdown-knitr-pandoc-beamer)

Comment: I was able to do it for each chunk with:
```{r, out.width = '750px', dpi=200} 

Since I have allot of plots on my document, How do I do it globally?

Comment: if that works, then in your first chunk, before you do any plots, add this inside the chunk like any regular R syntax: `opts_chunk$set(out.width='750px', dpi=200)`. see [chunk options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options#chunk_options)

Comment: Eric give the answer. How can one close a question in stackoverflow?

Comment: First, this question is not a duplicate of the other.  It is clearly about pixels, and thus HTML output, not about inches (LaTeX output, like the other).  Second, I don't find the answers sufficient, because the HTML output seems to cap the maximum image dimensions.  Using 1000px helps me a little, but I want it bigger; using 2000px gives identical results.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963962/plot-size-and-resolution-with-r-markdown-knitr-pandoc-beamer) for how to specify these details in chunks.

To set global chunk options, use `opts_chunk$set(out.width='750px', dpi=200)` inside your first chunk. See this page on [chunk options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options#chunk_options) for more.