# Rmarkdown / knitr / beamer figure size on slide

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, beamer

I would like to include a figure on a beamer slide produced by Rmarkdown / knitr. Setting the `fig.width` or `fig.height` options in the R code chunk changes the *relative* size of all plot elements (e.g. setting a smaller size makes fonts and geoms larger proportional to the plot area), but the plot still takes up most of the slide.

Instead, I would like to present a plot that takes up less area on the slide. How can I do that?

Note that this is a different question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963962/plot-size-and-resolution-with-r-markdown-knitr-pandoc-beamer?rq=1), which is asking about how to produce vector graphics. My figures are saved as pdf.

**EDIT**: after trying some more examples, it seems I just needed to be more extreme in my resizing and to manually adjust the base font size in the ggplot2 theme.

Sorry! My bad.

Reproducible example:

````
```{r logit, fig.width=1.5, fig.height=1.1}
library(ggplot2)
tmp <- data.frame(x = seq(-5, 5, length.out = 50))
tmp$y <- plogis(tmp$x)
plt <- ggplot(tmp, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  xlab("Linear predictor") + ylab("Probability") + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 8)
plt
```
````

Comment: You should post something reproducible.  We don't know what `plt` or `myfig` is.  The default `plot` function respects `fig.width` and `fig.height`.

Comment: In developing a minimal example I realised I was just not being extreme enough in resizing. Sorry.

Comment: That's one reason minimally reproducible examples are useful:  it's pretty common that you solve your own problem while producing one.