# Increase grid.arrange plot size

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm using grid.arrange to display the following three plots on top of each other.

```
p1 <- ggseasonplot(ng2) + labs(title = "Natural Gas Consumption from Jan. 2001 to Nov. 2021 - Seasonal Plot", x = "Month", y = "Cubic Feet (Millions)") + scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6))
p2 <- ggsubseriesplot(ng2) + labs(title = "Natural Gas Consumption from Jan. 2001 to Nov. 2021 - Subseries Plot", x = "Month", y = "Cubic Feet (Millions)") + scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6))
p3 <- ggAcf(ng2, lag.max = 36) + labs(title = "Natural Gas Consumption from Jan. 2001 to Nov. 2021 - ACF Plot", x = "Lag", y = "Correlation") 

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, nrow = 3, ncol = 1)
```

The resulting plots are unreadable.

[image: Here is the resulting output.]

Using the heights function only seems to adjust plot size relative to one another. Any idea how to make each plot larger (longer) as a whole so each is more readable?

Comment: Have you checked `cowplot::plot_grid(rel_width, rel_height)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your markdown/knitr chunk, try a value like `fig.height = 10`

````
```{r, fig.height = 10}
# Small fig.width
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point()
```
````

Or you can set the default height for all the figures in an Rmd file

```r
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.height = 10)
```

References

- https://community.rstudio.com/t/rmarkdown-rnotebook-text-in-graphs-too-small-lines-to-thin-after-update/123741/3
- http://zevross.com/blog/2017/06/19/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown-documents/
- [Plot size and resolution with R markdown, knitr, pandoc, beamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963962/plot-size-and-resolution-with-r-markdown-knitr-pandoc-beamer)
- https://rmd4sci.njtierney.com/customising-your-figures.html

Comment: This happens when rendering into HTML markdown. Is there a way to apply a figure height to a single chunk of code instead of the entire document?

Comment: At the top of the chunk put: ```{r fig.height=5, fig.width=8}

Comment: The first example applies to just a chunk.  The second example applies to the whole document.